# CSS bug - no trace

Tags: css, position, css-float

We are doing a webshop, and created a bug:

http://konzolbazis.hu

When you click on the background, and hit the right cursor key, the whole middle content will slide...

Tried finding the cause of the problem, but no trace found, floatations and positioning messed somehow.

(I know, the css is messy, constant changes made by the million demand of the client...yet to clean the code.)

Please help.

EDIT: using firefox 11.

Comment: Doesn't occur on Chrome 18.0.1025.162. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Ash: Chrome 10?? Chrome is up to v 18 now. It's happening in Chrome 18.

Comment: I was a bit perplexed by that too. However, I can't reproduce the issue in Chrome 18. Nor Firefox 9.0.1 & 11

Comment: Look below it was the sf.navbar... I figured it out by deleting the subnav element. from the DOM

Answer (score 3):

Did you notice the scrollbar at the bottom of the screen? The problem is, that you manually set widths inside the top menu (`ul.sf-menu`). Inside the `<li>` tags are addional `<ul>` tags with `width: 965px`. Delete them and everything will be fine.

Comment: When I deleted, the width of the submenu (the ul in the li) elements collapsed, and instead of appearing in-line, they made a column. How is that?

Comment: This is, because you are floating to much.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand that `width:auto` set the element width to acquire the full width of the Parent and specifying it explicitly creates a problem. If you want to set width such that the element acquires only the space required by itself not not that available from parent you may consider specifying it in percentage like `width:78.33%`. This makes sure that the element takes `78.33%` of the width of the parent.
The Container width is set manually which needs to be corrected. You'd need to set it as

`#container
{
width:auto;
}`

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT:

was:

```
 .sf-navbar {
    height: 79px;
    position: relative;
  }
```

should be:

```
.sf-navbar {
    display: block;
    height: 111px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, the overflow was what I wanted...and I SWEAR I will not make such mess of a code next time...probably will clean it too.

Comment: It's always good to refactor, and this bug is an ODD one for sure. I've never seen this before. It has something to do with the width of the LI elements inside of it, and the selectable area... but I tried playing with those and the whole page breaks.